# Admob status back to inactive

Tags: android, admob

I have new app that uses Admob. In the Admob Sites & Apps page, it was showed up as active a few days ago. But all of a sudden now the status is back to inactive and the hover text says

> Inactive: AdMob has never received an ad request for your site..

On my test device I get the test ad, but if I turn off the addTestDevice() line, I get no advert at all, and I get this in logcat:

> onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)

I'm getting more active users, so there definitely should be some hits. I'm completely lost!

Does anyone know if this is normal, as in I'm just getting a fill rate of 0, and the status is just misleading? Or is something wrong, and I need to change something?

Comment: same here.... same here....

Answer (score 1):

The key is here

```
(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory)
```

Everything is working fine, but there are no specific ads for your country / location / settings / etc. Check the ad's settings on the Admob control panel to make sure you're not blocking any categories that prevent you from receiving ads.

(If it says it has never received a request from your app / site, then check the Admob ID number in your code as it is probably incorrect unless you are definitely getting zero hits / requests)

Comment: no, the code is correct, it;s the latest SDK, I checked it and rechecked it. The app worked good and they were ads from my region. I have similar apps and they recieve ads. The problem I think.... I got suspended by Admob by some copyright etc. issues.